# how to make a custom sphinx role that is also an external link?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm trying to extend Sphinx to have a new inline role called `newcontrib`. What it should do is take its content and (1) add some extra text to it, (2) make the text bold in the rendered output, and (3) make the text a link, whose target is the original content of the role. Example:

```
:newcontrib:`Jane Doe`
```

Should end up being parsed as if it were

```
`**new contributor Jane Doe** <Jane Doe_>`_
```

The target is defined in another file (`names.inc`) and looks like:

```
.. _Jane Doe: https://jane-does-website.com
```

My attempt so far (based loosely on [this example](https://doughellmann.com/posts/defining-custom-roles-in-sphinx/)) is this:

```py
from docutils.nodes import reference, strong, target
from sphinx.addnodes import pending_xref


def newcontrib_role(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={},
                    content=[]):
    """Create a role to highlight new contributors in changelog entries."""
    newcontrib = f'new contributor {text}'
    targ = f' <{text}_>'
    rawtext = f'`{newcontrib}{targ}`_'
    options.update(name=newcontrib, refname=text.lower())
    strong_node = strong(rawtext, newcontrib)
    node = reference('', '', strong_node, **options)
    return [node], []


def setup(app):
    app.add_role('newcontrib', newcontrib_role)
    return
```

I've also tried using `pending_xref()` instead of `reference()`, and tried explicitly making a `target` node and adding it as a sibling. Results vary depending on exactly what I try; sometimes I get an error during build (missing attribute refname, refdomain, reftype...), other times I get a successful build but the link goes to `url-of-current-page#jane-doe`. I also briefly tried subclassing `XRefRole` instead of defining the role function... open to any approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ended up working was this:

```py
def newcontrib_role(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={},
                    content=[]):
    """Create a role to highlight new contributors in changelog entries."""
    newcontrib = f'new contributor {text}'
    alias_text = f' <{text}_>'
    rawtext = f'`{newcontrib}{alias_text}`_'
    refname = text.lower()
    strong_node = strong(rawtext, newcontrib)
    target_node = target(alias_text, refname=refname, names=[newcontrib])
    target_node.indirect_reference_name = text
    options.update(name=newcontrib, refname=refname)
    ref_node = reference('', '', strong_node, **options)
    ref_node[0].rawsource = rawtext
    inliner.document.note_indirect_target(target_node)
    inliner.document.note_refname(ref_node)
    return [ref_node, target_node], []
```

(plus the `setup(app)` function as in the question)

in particular, the key steps I hadn't tried before were `inliner.document.note_indirect_target` and `inliner.document.note_refname`. I got the idea from looking at [how docutils parses links](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/docutils/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py#l803).